# How can I evaluate this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to evaluate this limit but I am unsuccessful:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt[n]{e}+\sqrt[n]{e^2}+\cdots++\sqrt[n]{e^{n-1}}}{n}$$
I have to do it with Riemann sum (by converting it to a definite integral), but I am stuck. I wrote it like that (I hope that's correct):
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt[n]{e^{k-1}} $$

I guess I should take the intervals to have length $\frac{1}{n}$, but I don't know how to find the function $f(x)$ to integrate. What bothers me the most is that $n$-th root that I don't know what to do with. I was also thinking of somehow applying $\ln$, but I don't know how.

Comment: \begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt[n]{e}+\sqrt[n]{e^2}+\cdots++\sqrt[n]{e^{n-1}}}{n}
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt[n]{e^{k-1}} \\&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{e-1}{e^{1/n}-1}\right) \\&=
(e-1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n(e^{1/n}-1)}\\&=
(e-1)\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{u}{e^u-1} \\&= 
e-1
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is of the form
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{k-1}{n}}.
\end{align*}
It is of the left endpoint taken with the partition $\{0,1/n,...,(n-1)/n,1\}$, so it converges to the integral $\int_{0}^{1}e^{x}dx$.